# Can I pass a regex to isa() with Moose-based objects?

Tags: perl, moose

Can I use isa in Moose with a regex as a parameter ? If not possible can I achieve the same thing with someothing other than `->isa` ?

ok, having the following types  `Animal::Giraffe` , `Animal::Carnivore::Crocodile` , I want to do `->isa(/^Animal::/)`, can I do that ? if I can't, what can I use to reach the desired effect ?

Answer (score 8):

These related types should all "do" the same role, Animal.  Then you can write:

```
has 'animal' => (
    is       => 'ro',
    does     => 'Animal',
    required => 1,
);
```

Now you have something much more reliable than a regex to ensure the consistency of your program.

Answer (score 4):

Leon Timmermans' answer was close to what I'd suggest though I'd use the sugar from Moose::Util::TypeConstraints

```
use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

subtype Animal => as Object => where { blessed $_ =~ /^Animal::/ };

has animal => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Animal' );
```

Answer (score 4):

Extending perigrin's answer so that it will work if the class has an `Animal::*` anywhere in its superclasses, and not only in its immediate class name (for example if `Helper::Monkey` isa `Animal::Monkey`):

```
use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

subtype Animal => 
  as Object =>
  where { grep /^Animal::/, $_->meta->linearized_isa };

has animal => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Animal' );
```

I think jrockway's suggestion to use a role instead has a lot of merit, but if you want to go this way instead, you might as well cover all of the bases.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it.

```
use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

my $animal = Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint->new(
    constraint => sub { $_[0] =~ /^Animal::/}
);

has animal => (is => 'rw', isa => $animal);
```

ETA: I agree with jrockway though: unless you have a convincing reason otherwise, you should just use inheritance.

Comment: Nit-picky point of correction, `does` checks for role composition rather than inheritance. I also agree that checking for role composition is preferable :) Anal-retentive moment over.